# Get empty image when transcoding SVG to PNG

Tags: java, png, svg, batik, transcode

I'm trying to generate an SVG image and then transcode it to PNG using Apache Batik. However, I end up with an empty image and I can't see why.

I use the Document from SVGDomImplementation as the base for my transcoding (to avoid writing the SVG to disk and loading it again). Here's an example:

```
  DOMImplementation domImpl = SVGDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
  String namespace = SVGDOMImplementation.SVG_NAMESPACE_URI;
  Document document = domImpl.createDocument(namespace, "svg", null);

  //stuff that builds SVG (and works)

  TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(svgGenerator.getDOMFactory());
  PNGTranscoder transcoder = new PNGTranscoder();
  transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(svgWidth));
  transcoder.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new Float(svgHeight));

  try {
     File temp = File.createTempFile(key, ".png");
     FileOutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(temp); 

     TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(outputstream);

     transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, output);
     outputstream.flush();
     outputstream.close();
     name = temp.getName();
  } catch (IOException ioex) {
     ioex.printStackTrace();
  } catch (TranscoderException trex) {
     trex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

My problem is that the resulting image is empty and I can't see why. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how you're creating the SVG document.  What are you using `svgGenerator` for (which I assume is an `SVGGraphics2D`)?

```
TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(svgGenerator.getDOMFactory());
```

If you've built up the SVG document in `document`, then you should pass it to the `TranscoderInput` constructor.

[This page](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html#genImagefromSVGDOM) has an example of rasterizing an SVG DOM to a JPEG.

Comment: Correct, the svgGenerator is an SVGGraphics2D. The getDOMFactory() returns the same document/object as the one I create in the beginning of the method, so it makes no difference.

I've already been over the JPEG example several times. Perhaps it isn't enough to change that example to PNG (I didn't really TEST that particular example), and maybe the PNG transcoder needs some other/extra settings that I'm not seeing.

I solved my actual problem (getting the SVG into a PDF properly) in another way, so this isn't needed any longer.